# PHP - fgetcsv - Delimiter being ignored?

Tags: php, delimiter, fgetcsv

I'm trying to output each line in a csv file, and it seems like the delimiter is being ignored... I'm sure my syntax is wrong somewhere, but can't seem to pinpoint it...

The CSV file looks like this:

```
ID,Code,Count
TM768889,02001,10
TM768889,02002,10
TM768889,02003,10
TM768889,02004,10
TM768889,02005,10
```

I'm trying to output:

```
   0 - ID,Code,Count
   1 - TM768889,02001,10
   2 - TM768889,02002,10
   3 - TM768889,02003,10
   4 - TM768889,02004,10
   5 - TM768889,02005,10
```

But instead, it's outputting this:

```
0 - ID
1 - Code
2 - Count TM768889
3 - 02001
4 - 10 TM768889
5 - 02002
6 - 10 TM768889
7 - 02003
8 - 10 TM768889
9 - 02004
10 - 10 TM768889
11 - 02005
12 - 10
```

Here's my code:

```
  $row = 0;
  if(($handle = fopen($_FILES["Filedata"]["tmp_name"], "r")) !== FALSE) {
              $string = '';
              while(($line = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !== FALSE) {
                    $num = count($line);
                    $row++;
                    for($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                              $string .= $c.' - '.$line[$c].'<br />';
            }
          }     
  fclose($handle);
  echo $string;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother with `fgetcsv`? You're just taking the line and spitting it back out, so it seems like you could just use `fgets` instead:

```
  $row = 0;
  if(($handle = fopen($_FILES["Filedata"]["tmp_name"], "r")) !== FALSE) {
              $string = '';
              while(($line = fgets($handle)) !== FALSE) {
                    $row++;
                    $string .= $row.' - '.$line.'<br />';
            }
          }     
  fclose($handle);
  echo $string;
  }
```

Your problem is that you are printing out a full line for each value in the CSV file, rather than the line as a whole like you intend.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your code does not print what you pasted. The counter does not match the $c variable.

This is what I get:

```
0 - ID
1 - Code
2 - Count
0 - TM768889
1 - 02001
2 - 10
0 - TM768889
1 - 02002
2 - 10
0 - TM768889
1 - 02003
2 - 10
0 - TM768889
1 - 02004
2 - 10
0 - TM768889
1 - 02005
2 - 10
```

If your data file is not huge then I advise you to load the file into an array using the file() function. Then you can loop thru the array and output the value which is simply the line.

```
$lines=file($_FILES["Filedata"]["tmp_name"]);
foreach($lines as $line) print($line.'<br/>');
```

If you then need to parse the line then just use the explode() function to get at each value.